# how to synchronize and backup files

Tags: ansible

I am writing a playbook to synchronize a number of files.  If the files have changed then I need to back them up and overwrite them with the source files.  Not sure how to do this.  Right now It is not overwriting the the destination files.

```
  - name:  "Copies files over"
    synchronize:
      src: "{{ item.source }}"
      dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
      recursive: yes
    notify:
      restart freeswitch
    with_items:
      - { source: '/Users/User1/Documents/Ansible/files/sca/dialplan/', dest: '/etc/freeswitch' }
      - { source: '/Users/User1/Documents/Ansible/files/sca/sip_profiles/', dest: '/etc/freeswitch' }
      - { source: '/Users/User1/Documents/Ansible/files/sca/scripts/', dest: '/usr/share/freeswitch/scripts' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you doing it on local ansible server ?

because synchronize module only running on local ansible server. can not excute on remote server.